# How can I compare 2 different arrays index wise?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

From Index wise I mean:
If there are two arrays `A` and `B` then, the item at index 0 in array `A` compares to item at index 0 in array `B`.

Here is the example to work on:

```
let start = ['m', 'y', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'];

let end = ['y', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'];
```

You must not do it this way(`(a[1] === b[1])`) because you don't know how long the array can be

Comment: Loop through the array indexes, comparing the corresponding elements.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: The result can be true if they are equal or else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a standard for-loop to iterate over the indices of the `start` (or `end`) array. While looping, you can check the values for each array at that index and compare them.

You only return `true` if you do not break out of the function early.

```js
function areEqual(start, end) {
  if (start === end) {
    return true; // Same memory address
  }
  if (start.length !== end.length) {
    console.error('Length of arrays do not match!');
    return false;
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < start.length; index++) {
    if (start[index] !== end[index]) {
      console.error(`Values at index ${index} do not match`);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; // Equal!
}

const start = ['m', 'y', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'];
const end = ['y', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'];

console.log(areEqual(start, end));
```

Here is an ES6 version, but it does not have error-checking. It simply returns `true` or `false`.

```js
const
  start    = ['m', 'y', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'],
  end      = ['y', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'],
  other    = ['m', 'y', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'i', 's'],
  areEqual = (a, b) =>
               (a === b) || (a.length === b.length && !a.some((x, i) => x !== b[i]));

console.log(areEqual(start, end));   // Diff  -- false
console.log(areEqual(start, start)); // Same  -- true
console.log(areEqual(start, other)); // Equal -- true
```